# Will Python automatically detect that the function was never called but defined?

Tags: python

True or False

If a function is defined but never called, then Python automatically detects that and issues a warning

Comment: Did you try it? :)

Comment: Python itself would not detect this. Some IDEs can detect unused code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues with this is that functions in Python are first class objects.  So their name can be reassigned.  For example:

```
def myfunc():
     pass

a = myfunc
myfunc = 42

a()
```

We also have *closures*, where a function is returned by another function and the original name goes out of scope.

Unfortunately it is also perfectly legal to define a function with the same name as an existing one.  For example:

```
def myfunc():       #  <<< This code is never called
    pass

def myfunc():
    pass

myfunc()
```

So any tracking must include the function's `id`, not just its name - although that won't help with closures, since the `id` could get reused.  It also won't help if the `__name__` attribute of the function is reassigned.

You could track function calls using a decorator.  Here I have used the name and the `id` - the `id` on its own would not be readable.

```
import functools
globalDict = {}

def tracecall(f):

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global globalDict
        key = "%s (%d)" % (f.__name__, id(f))

        # Count the number of calls
        if key in globalDict:
            globalDict[key] += 1
        else:
            globalDict[key] = 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@tracecall 
def myfunc1():
     pass

myfunc1()
myfunc1()

@tracecall
def myfunc1():
     pass

a = myfunc1
myfunc1 = 42

a()

print(globalDict)
```

Gives:

```
{'myfunc1 (4339565296)': 2, 'myfunc1 (4339565704)': 1}
```

**But that only gives the functions that have been called, not those that have not!**

So where to go from here?  I hope you can see that the task is quite difficult given the dynamic nature of python.  But I hope the decorator I show above could at least allow you to diagnose the way the code is used.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Python is not detect this. If you want to detect which functions are called or not during the run time you can use global set in your program. Inside each function add function name to set. Later you can print your set content and check if the the function is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

False. Ignoring the difficulty and overhead of doing this, there's no reason why it would be useful.

A function that is defined in a module (i.e. a Python file) but not called elsewhere in that module might be called from *a different* module, so that doesn't deserve a warning.

If Python were to analyse all modules that get run over the course of a program, and print a warning about functions that were not called, it may be that a function was not called because of the input in this particular run e.g. perhaps in a calculator program there is a "multiply" function but the user only asked to sum some numbers.

If Python were to analyse all modules that make up a program and note and print a warning about functions that could not possibly be called (this is impossible but stay with me here) then it would warn about functions that were intended for use in other programs. E.g. if you have two calculator programs, a simple one and an advanced one, maybe you have a central `calc.py` with utility functions, and then advanced functions like `exp` and `log` could not possibly be called when that's used as part of simple program, but that shouldn't cause a warning because they're needed for the advanced program.